# how to make the close bracket ")" in line with the printed line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

good day. I'm still a newbie and I encounter a small problem with my code.

```
f = open('pfile.txt', 'r')
line_count = 0
for data in f:
    first, last, pay = data.split('~')
    line_count += 1
    print('emp_{} = Employee({}, {}, {})'.format(line_count, first, last, pay), end='')

f.close()
```

this is the pfile.txt

```
iring~asd~250
asxx~das~200
baading~asd~3000
```

this is the output.

```
emp_1 = Employee(iring, asd, 250
)emp_2 = Employee(asxx, das, 200
)emp_3 = Employee(baading, asd, 3000
)
```

I want it to be like this

```
emp_1 = Employee(iring, asd, 250)
emp_2 = Employee(asxx, das, 200)
emp_3 = Employee(baading, asd, 3000)
```

please help me how to fix this close bracket ")" in line with the printed line. thank you in advance :)

Comment: If any answer here helped you, you can accept it by clicking on the big checkmark to select it as the accepted answer, so people answering can focus on older questions which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable `pay` contains the newline character at the end.  Therefore you need to remove it when printing.  For this you can do `pay[:-1]` which reads: all characters of `pay` from the first one (included) to the last one (excluded).

```py
f = open('pfile.txt', 'r')
line_count = 0
for data in f:
    first, last, pay = data.split('~')
    line_count += 1
    print('emp_{} = Employee({}, {}, {})'.format(line_count, first, last, pay[:-1]))

f.close()
```

Note that to avoid using `close` (which can be easily forgotten) on the file you can rewrite your code as:

```py
with open('pfile.txt', 'r') as f:
  line_count = 0
  for data in f:
      first, last, pay = data.split('~')
      line_count += 1
      print('emp_{} = Employee({}, {}, {})'.format(line_count, first, last, pay[:-1]))
```

The file is automatically closed when the `with` statement terminates.

Answer (score 2):

When you read the lines, the newline is also read in which is inserted in the format string. You can do the following:

```
f = open('pfile.txt', 'r')
line_count = 0
for data in f:
    first, last, pay = data.strip().split('~')
    line_count += 1
    print('emp_{} = Employee({}, {}, {})'.format(line_count, first, last, pay), end='')

f.close()
```